# How to load php form submit on the same page in div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have got Catalog and search bar(katalog3.php) in php , but funcionality in others files (search bar funcioanliy is search_example.php and catalogue funconality is example_show_model_detail.php) for now they display in funcionality page .... but i want the results of this be display(in katalog3.php) in concrete div(class="results") . How Can i achive it?

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="example_show_model_details.php">
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<form  method="post" id="fname" action="search_example.php">
Wyszukaj<input type="text" name="duren" id="duren"><br>
<button type="submit" form="fname" value="Submit">Submit1</button>
</form>
</div>  
<div class="results">
</div>
```

Comment: I want this two Forms  Submit and Submit 1 display on the same page in div class= Results

Answer (score 0):

From what I am reading it seems like you are looking for an ajax call to send data to another script and receive the response. If you are using jquery you can read more about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. In the event you are not using jquery you may want to take a look at this post: [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery).

Comment: I need precis info or code example I newbie in php and jquery

Comment: This site is not for people to write code for you. I am pointing you in the right direction. Everyone here who is able to write the code for you took their own time to learn it. You should do the same it will help you out in the long run. The page I linked you has adequate information on how to setup the ajax call using jquery. If you are absolutely stuck then you need to let people know where and what you are stuck on.

Comment: I stuck beacuse i cant fiugre how to Display results of two Forms  Submit  and Submit1 on the same page in div

Comment: @kancer so you have already created the ajax call? Can you update your question to include the javascript as well if possible. I might be able to help you out if you can do that.

Comment: i will try to write it